# Get user data in Craft CMS Personal edition

Tags: users

Like I am stating in the title, I am using the free Craft Personal edition which is perfect for my portfolio.

I already (and obviously) have an account and only one.
So I cannot have access to `craft.users` but this account already have my Full Name and Email written in it and I want to use those in my website without having to redo them as Globals.

Is that possible in Craft Personal?

I thought I will be able to use `{{ account }}` but it is only accessible in the Registration Form as I can see.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible with a simple plugin that registers its own Twig extension.  Head over to https://pluginfactory.io/ and check the "Twig Extensions" option to have it generate the boilerplate code for you.

100% untested, but in your `PluginNameTwigExtension.php` file, add a `getGlobals()` method that does something like this:

```
public function getGlobals()
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
    $criteria->admin = true;
    $user = $criteria->first();

    return array('adminAccount' => $user);
}
```

Then every template should have a global `adminAccount` variable available to it that's a [UserModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/UserModel) object, so you can do things like `{{ adminAccount.firstName }}`.

Comment: Just tested it and it works like a charm ! 
Exactly like you said.

Thank you a lot.